# Possible to include Mono Runtimes in OSX .app bundle?

Tags: c#, macos, mono

I'm looking to work on an application that needs to run on both Windows and OSX.  Since I'm already very familiar with C#/.NET I thought I would take a look at using Mono.  But I also want it to very easy to install and don't want the users to have to install the Mono package separately.  Is it possible to create an OS X .app bundle that simply includes EVERYTHING?  That is, my app, resources and the complete Mono runtime?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Yes, you can do this.  Pick an app, any app, and Show Package Contents.  Explore around a bit and you'll see that there's a Contents/MacOS directory inside.  It will contain a file with the execute bit set.  This can be machine code or any old script with a `#!` line at the beginning.  All you need to do is duplicate the directory structure with a skeleton app, shove your Mono runtime into the Resources directory somewhere, and write a bash script that initializes everything.  There may be automated utilities for doing this floating around somewhere, but it's pretty easy to do this manually.

I'd recommend using your favorite build tool to automate this process.

Comment: Thanks.  In any case, it really depends on what you mean by "not recommended".  If you did it 100% manually, then yeah, absolutely, that's a bad idea.  Would be some serious deployment issues there.  But the first step to automating something is knowing how to do it manually.  To clarify, if there's no pre-built packaging tool to do this for the Mono runtime, write a quick script to automate this, and insert it into your build process.

Comment: By "initializes everything", what do you mean? Do you mean that it starts calls a command line function like "mono hello.exe"? Could you point us to a link? Thanks.

Comment: Yes, that's what I mean, though you could really do anything you want there.  In fact, you could potentially have that script be the entire program.  However, if you're going to pass control to another program, I recommend using `exec` to do it.  I don't really have a link since I discovered this by experimentation.

Comment: This answer really and totally ignores the question of the Mono dependency.  The Mono framework still has to be installed, unless you embed the framework into a native OS targeted executable.

Comment: Sorry, I glossed over that because it's not exactly rocket science, but yes, you would want to embed the entire framework in your .app package. That's a simple matter of copying it into the `Contents/Resources` directory somewhere.

Comment: Looks like people have Mono apps on the App Store and that having some complicated step of installing the Mono package after installing your app is obviously a no-no. For us in this question, it certainly makes some easy Googling! http://www.mono-project.com/MonoMacPackager#Mac_AppStore_Distribution

Comment: Yeah, just stuff it in Contents/Resources. Couldn't be simpler. This applies to *any* app on the Mac. For reference in case anyones wondering, this isn't the same for IOS since IOS doesn't allow dynamic linking for some messed up reason. I'd suggest finding a packaged turnkey Mono osx app and having a study of its internal organs.

Answer (score 2):

It is possible, with quite a bit of hacking and some toolchain fun to compile a .NET app statically targeted for the Mac OS platform, no need to deploy mono with it.  Check out this website talking about how Mono is being used statically in some iPhone apps.

http://arstechnica.com/open-source/news/2009/01/open-source-mono-framework-brings-c-to-iphone-and-wii.ars

Another great resource is the #mono channel on irc.gnome.org or irc.gimp.net (http://mono-project.com/IRC)

Comment: This isnt really necesary on the mac. IOS needs to do this because of its strict static linking only policy. Mac has no such restraints.